# QGIS 3.6: Vector "Polygons to Lines" missing

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-3

I use the tool **Vector-->Geometry Tools-->Polygons to Lines** all the time.  It is in the menu up until 3.4. In 3.6, that menu item is no longer available.  Where did it go?  Is there another way to do this in 3.6?

Comment: Could you search for it from the _Processing Toolbox_?

Answer (score 3):

This bug was reported and should be fixed in the next update:

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21475

Comment: In the meantime, just use the processing toolbox to access it